# how to pass a data between two activities without intent

Tags: android, bundle, android-spinner

i have a spinner and a button for registration. the spinner works as...

```
typeofcompany.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ba = typeofcompany.getSelectedItem().toString();
            typeofcompany.getItemAtPosition(i);

            sss = companycode.get(i);
            SelectType(companycode.get(i));
            sessionmanager.tosaveRegionName(sss);



        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

when i select an item of the spinner,that item should be passed inside the  button's Activity.
i have used the bundle method for the same
like

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustRegActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("spinneritem", abc);
startActivity(intent);
```

but this startActivity(intent) is directly getting me inside the the second activity. i just want to send the data withour intent how can i do that....

Comment: have you tried LocalBroadcastManager?

``Intent intent = new Intent("localReceiver");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FirstActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);``

Comment: Have you tried to declare the data in global and static variables?

Comment: Try using interface

Comment: data is global @Brank Victoria

Comment: Have you tried to use `SharedPreferences`? Save to `SharedPreferences` from the 1st `Activity`, when you want to open the 2nd `Activity` then load them from `SharedPreferences`

Comment: let me try with the sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of shared preferences. In my case i usually use TinyDB which is very easy to use.
go ahead and sync this statement in your gradle

```
compile 'com.mukesh:tinydb:1.0.1'
```

Usage is quite simple.
Just create a new instance of tinyDB and pass the application context. This way

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
```

initiate it in the onCreate, then store data this way :

```
tinyDB.putString("spinneritem", abc);
```

You can retrieve this string from any activity in the app. In the activity you want to get the data declare a new instance of TinyDB once more just as shown above and retrieve the data stored in the following way:

```
tinyDB.getString("spinneritem");
```

You can store all variable types this way, whether its int,boolean or even arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a method to the second activity like this

`public void setSpinnerItem(String abc){
    .....
}`

to set a variable(or static variable) to save the content,

then call it in onItemSelected in the first activity

or better
add a observer interface in first activity with a method called onSpinnerItemSelected(String abc), then set the observer in the second activity.

you can also save the data in the first activity in sp, sqlitedb, or simply in a data class's instance variables, then get them in the second activity